# Select records from table A that have at least X records on table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `users` another table called `user_flags`, and another table called `flags`

The `users` table contains a `name` and `id`

The `flags` table contains a `name` and `id`

The `user_flags` contains a `user_id` and `flag_id`

If I want to get all the users which have any of the provided flag names, what would be the query? That is, if the query provides 'red' and 'blue' but a user is just associated with blue, we would return that User.

That is, if I have the following schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac105 - And the flag names that I passed were `red` and `blue`, it would return the row for the User John, because John has a `red` associated flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables on their id values and use a where clause for the flag color name. Something like this:

```
select * from Users U
  join UsersFlags UF on UF.user_id = U.id
  join Flags F on F.id = UF.flag_id
  where F.name = 'red'
```

Comment: What if I want to use several names? Say I want to get the users which have associated flags which names are either: 'red', 'blue', 'green', etc

Comment: You could then change the where clause to something like: `where F.name in ('red', 'blue', 'green')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u INNER JOIN user_flags uf
ON u.id = uf.user_id
INNER JOIN flags f
ON uf.flag_id = f.id
WHERE F.name = 'red'
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac105/3)

Note that in the fiddle the table and column names are slightly different from what you used in your original question.

Comment: where is the condition for name here? Maybe my question was not clear, but I want to find the Users which have flags which names are within a given set of names. So if John has flags red and in the query I have the flag names ['red', 'blue'] - John would be part of the response.

Comment: `"get all the users which have **any** given flag names"` ... My query will filter out all users who do _not_ have a corresponding flag (name).  Is your understanding of the OP different?

Comment: edited to clarify what I was looking for. Sorry. By **any** I meant, that they don't need to satisfy all of them, but just any of the given ones (given in the query).

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause to your taste.  I updated the query to only retain users who have a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT s.id,s.name 
FROM @users s 
JOIN @users_flag uf ON s.id = uf.uid
JOIN @flag f ON f.id = uf.fid
WHERE f.NAME IN ('red','Blue')
```

Comment: `@users`  is an invalid identifier in SQL

Comment: in my case i create a temporary tables.

Comment: It's still invalid SQL and will not work in Postgres

Comment: DECLARE @user TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(10)) 
insert values in this temporary table and use it in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id
      ,u.name
      ,f.name flag 
FROM USERS u
     JOIN flags f using(id)
     JOIN UsersFlags uf on f.id=uf.flag_id
WHERE
f.name in ('red','blue') -- or f.name in (select name from flags)
                         -- or f.name = any(array['red','blue'])
```

and another one

```
SELECT u.NAME
FROM USERS u
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT uf.user_id
        FROM UsersFlags uf
        JOIN flags f ON uf.flag_id = f.id
        WHERE f.NAME IN (
                'red'
                ,'blue'
                )
        )
```

output:

```
id name flag 
-- ---- ---- 
1  John red
```